# Ngrx Reducer/effects not triggered

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

I am trying a poc on ngrx , reducer is not triggered . Here is my code

**Action file.ts**

```
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";
import { PocInfo } from "../entity";

export const GET_POC = '[Build Call] Get Poc';
export const GET_POC_SUCCESS = '[Build Call] Get Poc Success';
export const GET_POC_FAILURE = '[Build Call] Get Poc Failure';

export const getPocs = createAction(GET_POC);
export const getPocSuccess = createAction(
  GET_POC_SUCCESS,
  props<any>()
)

export const getPocFailure = createAction(
  GET_POC_FAILURE,
  props<{message: string}>()
)
```

**Index.ts  // same path**

```
  export{GET_POC,getPocs,getPocSuccess,getPocFailure} from './poc.actions';
```

**Reducer.ts**

```
import { Action, createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import * as pocActions from '../actions';

export interface State {
    data?:any,
    status?:string
  }

  export const initialState: State = {
    data:[],
    status:'INITIAL'
  };

  const pocReducer = createReducer(
      initialState,  
    on(pocActions. getPocs, (state) => ({...state, status: 'INITIAL'})),
    on(pocActions. getPocSuccess, (state, result) => {
        return {data: result.response,status:'SUCCESS'}
    }),
   );
   export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action): any {
    return pocReducer(state, action);
  }
  
  export const getPocs = (state: State) => {
    return {
        data: state.data,
        status: state.status
    };
  };
```

**Index.ts**

```
import {
  ActionReducerMap,
  createFeatureSelector,
  createSelector,
} from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromPoc from './reducers/poc.reducer';
export interface State {
  poc:fromPoc.State  
}
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  poc:fromPoc.reducer
};
// Poc 
export const getPocState = createFeatureSelector<fromPoc.State>('poc');
export const getPocs = createSelector(
  getPocState,
  fromPoc.getPocs
);
```

**Entity.ts**

```
export class PocInfo {
    data?: any;
    status?: string;
 }
```

**Index.ts// Same path**

```
export {PocInfo} from './poc.entity';
```

**app.service.ts**

```
getPoc(){
    return of({data:['123','456'],status:'SUCCESS'})
  }
```

**Effects.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, exhaustMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AppService } from '../../_services';
import * as pocActions from '../actions';

@Injectable()
export class PocEffects {

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private appService: AppService
  ) {}

  getPocs$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(pocActions.getPoc),
    exhaustMap(action =>
      this.appService.getPocs().pipe(
        map(response => {
          console.log("response:::", response)
          return pocActions.getPocSuccess({response})
        }),
        catchError((error: any) => of(pocActions. getPocFailure (error))))
    )
  )
);

}
```

Index.ts //samepath

```
export { PocEffects } from './poc.effects';
```

component.ts

```
ngOninit(){
  this.store.select(fromRoot.getPocs).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data::::', data);
    });

  this.store.dispatch(pocActions.getPocs());
}
```

Comment: Any errors? What do you see in redux devtools? Are you sure your reducer is registered in your module…?

Comment: let me check that

Comment: Thanks , found the fix     Added effects in app module EffectsModule.forRoot([PocEffects])